# Dependence of Hall coefficient on temperature in copper

Tags: experimental-physics, magnetic-fields

As part of a project on the Hall Effect in metals, we would like to find out whether the Hall Coefficient of copper depends on its temperature, and if so how.

We passed a current I through a copper foil inside a magnetic field. We measured the Hall Voltage as a function of the current in the foil, using
$$ V_{\text{Hall}} = \left({B R_H\over\delta}\right)I $$
where $B$ is the magnetic field perpendicular to the foil, $R_H$ is the Hall coefficient, $I$ is the current through the foil and $\delta$ is the thickness of the foil. We also know that raising the temperature raises the resistivity $\rho$, but we do not know the dependence of $R_H$ on $\rho$.

By plotting the graph of $V_{\text{Hall}}$ as a function of $I$, we expected to find the known value of $R_H$ for copper. However, we found a somewhat larger value (by about 15-20%). We were wondering if a possible explanation could be the rise in temperature, caused by the very large currents (5-10Amps) used in the experiment.

Comment: It is impossible to tell what happened in your experiment without a precise description of what you used to do the measurement. This includes the size of the probe, the way you created and measured your magnetic field, temperature, voltages, currents etc.. Since your explanation of what you did sounds on the naive side (student experiment?), my naive guess would be that you had a non-trivial measurement error, but it's next to impossible to identify those without control experiments, i.e. you have to vary all parameters in controlled ways and see how the error changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be onto something. [This](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.4735) research paper on arXiv suggests a linear relation between the Hall coefficient and temperature for a certain strongly disordered metal; the analysis probably does **not** apply in your case with copper, but was included because it is interesting, is current research and deals with the relation between the hall coefficient and temperature. [This](https://www.nikhef.nl/%7Eh73/kn1c/praktikum/phywe/LEP/Experim/5_3_03.pdf) german experiment directly deals with the temperature dependence of the Hall coefficient of copper samples, relevant to your case; the result seems to indicate that the Hall coefficient is not temperature-dependent, but further mentions that inaccuracies in determining the hall coefficient of zinc samples may have something to do with certain contact effects and impurities:

> Among these we may mention the Ettinghausen effect, the Peltier effect, the Seebeck effect, the first Righi-Leduc effect and the
> first Ettinghausen-Nernst effect. lt is possibly due also to
> impurities in the test material (99.95 % purity).

These effects and some impurities most likely affected measurements, more likely than temperature.